# how can I get the next set of items from the crm.lead.list method?

Tags: php, rest, bitrix

I am trying to create a list of leads of more then 50 items so I encounterd the limit of the list method. On the training site I already found that I need to do a call to get the next set but I have found no mention of how that should be done in php all examples are in javascript so that is of no help.

The current method calls I have tried to get it working but I only get the same set as a result:

```php
$fistSet = CRest::call("crm.lead.list", [
  "order"=> [ "ID"=> "ASC" ],
  "filter"=> [ "UF_CRM_1600929716160"=> 632],
  "select"=> [ "ID", "TITLE", "STATUS_ID", "OPPORTUNITY", "CURRENCY_ID" ]
]);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($fistSet);
echo "</pre>";
echo "<br>----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------<br>";
$total = $firstSet["total"];
$next = $firstSet["next"];
$secondSet = CRest::call("crm.lead.list", [
  "order"=> [ "ID"=> "ASC" ],
  "filter"=> [ "UF_CRM_1600929716160"=> 632], "OFFSET"=>$next,
  "select"=> [ "ID", "TITLE", "STATUS_ID", "OPPORTUNITY", "CURRENCY_ID" ]
]);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($secondSet);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a PHP question, so much as a question relating to a specific 3rd party API and how they handle pagination. I'd suggest checking their documentation to see how they handle pagination in subsequent requests.

Comment: I added the php tag because this is done in php. Also I checked the documentation and it says "that I need to specifiy the value in 'next' to get the next set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is for Bitrix, their documentation says the response from `next` should be passed in a `start` property in your next request. So swap `offset` to `start`.

Comment: Hello @Aran , do you remember where did you find that in their documentation?